# codeigniter:fail to create captcha

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I am using captcha and I want to create a captcha using the cpatcha helper!I read the user guide and write a piece of code,but it fails to create an captcha,also here is no error displayed on the page,so I just can't find where I am wrong,my code is as follows:

```
public function captcha(){
        $this->load->helper('captcha');

        $vals=array(
            'word'=>'0123456789',
            'img_path'=>base_url('asserts/cpatcha').'/',
            'img_url'=>base_url('asserts/cpatcha').'/',
            'img_width'=>150,
            'img_height'=>30,
            'expiration'=>7200
            );

        var_dump($vals);
        $cap=create_captcha($vals);
        var_dump($cap['image']);
    }
```

as I print the two variables,the result displayed on the page is as follows:

```
array (size=6)
  'word' => string '0123456789' (length=10)
  'img_path' => string 'http://wrecruit.tudouya.com/asserts/cpatcha/' (length=44)
  'img_url' => string 'http://wrecruit.tudouya.com/asserts/cpatcha/' (length=44)
  'img_width' => int 150
  'img_height' => int 30
  'expiration' => int 7200

null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change
`$cap=create_captcha();`
to
`$cap = create_captcha($vals);`
and also change
`var_dump($cap['image']);`
to `echo $cap['image'];`

Comment: what is the result of "echo $cap['image'];" ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by myself and I post my solution at here,hope this can help others!
at first,the reason why the captcha can't display correctly due to the uncorrect config.it's this:`'img_path'=>base_url('asserts/cpatcha').'/',`.
I read the source code of captcha in ci and I find in the line 66-69,it will check if the img_path is a dir,just as follows:

```
if ( ! @is_dir($img_path))
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

in my config,I set the img_path to "base_url('asserts/cpatcha').'/'",this is not a dir,so it will fail to create the captcha.
the way to solve this is just setting the correct path which will store the captcha image.
hope this can help you!